# Java type casting generics list of list of child to list of list of parent

Tags: java, list, generics, casting

I have a class like `ChildData1` which extends from `Data`.
How can I convert a `List<List<ChildData1>>` to a `List<List<Data>>` ?

Comment: I saw that question earlier and we cannot apply the same solution here. Though similar, they are not same.

Comment: The extra list doesn't make a difference here.  The solution provided (along with the other answers) are still applicable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Under the rules of generics you can do the following assignment without the cast:

```
List<List<ChildData>> subClassList = ...
List<? extends List<? extends Data>> superClassList = subClassList;
```

Comment: Earlier i tried with List<List<? extends Data>>. Thanks Oleg.

Answer (score 0):

Traverse the elements of list and `TYPECAST` it.

Answer (score 0):

Imagine if you could do this:

```
List<List<ChildData1>> foo = getListOfListOfChildData();
List<List<Data>> bar = foo; // there's your cast

ChildData2 childData2 = getSomeOtherChildData();
bar.get(0).add(childData2); // now you've added ChildData2

for (ChildData1 childData1 : foo.get(0)) {
  // Whoops! Suddenly you've got a ChildData2 in your ChildData1.
}
```

These types are not naturally compatible, and not easily converted to one another without some kind of `@SuppressWarnings`.

Answer (score -1):

If Data is a parent no need to explicitly typecast it.

```
List<List<Data>>> data = somemethod();

List<List<ChildData>>> somemethod(){};
```

Comment: Type mismatch: cannot convert from List<List<ChildData>> to List<List<Data>>

Comment: childdata inherits the properties of parent data. It should

Comment: no, it shouldn't.  that type system would be unsound, just like array covariant subtyping is unsound.